# Establishing infinite number of solutions for a first order ordinary differential equation from two known solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to establish that a first order ordinary differential equation $y'=f(x,y), y(x_0)=y_0$ has infinitely many solutions on $\mathbb R$ if already two distinct solutions are known.

For instance, I was trying to find a third solution for $y'=4y^{\frac{3}{4}}, y(0)=1$, (where $y$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R$) distinct from $y_1=(x-1)^4$ and $y_2=(x+1)^4$.

Comment: Your function $f$ is not $C^1$. Do you know about the Cauchy-Lipschitz theory?

Comment: Is there any trouble with the $C^1$ condition of $f$? I just removed it.

Comment: If $f$ is $C^1$ the ODE has a unique maximal solution : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: If $f$ is $C^1(\mathbb R)$, Can we extend the interval $[x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon]$ mentioned in Picard's Lindeloff theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: With $f$ merely $C^1$ no you cannot. Are you looking for global solutions?

Comment: Any counter examples? Actually my doubt is how to establish the third solution for the aforementioned problem. Also, I want to know whether the problem $y'=P(y), y(x_0)=y_0$ for some polynomial $P$, has a unique solution on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131613/discussion-between-riyasudheen-t-k-and-blamethelag).